# How to eliminate negative space from a .png file

Tags: c#, wpf

In my WPF project I have this class that handles taking a snapshot of any given canvas and it exports it as a .PNG. However, when the file is exported I get an inmense amount of white space.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
public static class ExportAsPNG
  {
    public static void SaveCanvas(Window window, Canvas canvas, int dpi, string filename)
    {
      System.Windows.Size size = new System.Windows.Size(window.Width, window.Height);
      canvas.Measure(size);
      //canvas.Arrange(new Rect(size));

      var rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap(
          (int)window.Width, //width 
          (int)window.Height, //height 
          dpi, //dpi x 
          dpi, //dpi y 
          PixelFormats.Pbgra32 // pixelformat 
          );
      rtb.Render(canvas);

      SaveRTBAsPNG(rtb, filename);
    }

    private static void SaveRTBAsPNG(RenderTargetBitmap bmp, string filename)
    {
      var enc = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.PngBitmapEncoder();

      enc.Frames.Add(System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapFrame.Create(bmp));
      using (var stm = System.IO.File.Create(filename))
      {
        enc.Save(stm);
      }
    }    
  }
```

What I need help is understanding how to just capture the image and not the whole canvas. Many thanks in advance!

**UPDATED CODE**

```
  /// <summary>
  /// Handles the logic for taking a snapshot of any given canvas
  /// </summary>
  public static class ExportImage
  {
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a snapshot of the canvas and saves it as a bitmap
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="canvas">the current canvas</param>
    /// <param name="dpi">the desired dpi (96 is default)</param>
    /// <param name="filename">the desired file name</param>
    public static void SaveCanvas(Canvas canvas, int dpi, string filename)
    {
      RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap(
          (int)Convert.ToInt32(canvas.ActualWidth), //width 
          (int)canvas.ActualHeight, //height 
          dpi, //dpi x 
          dpi, //dpi y 
          PixelFormats.Pbgra32 // pixelformat 
          );
      rtb.Render(canvas);

      SaveRTBAsPNG(rtb, filename);      
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Takes the target bitmap and converts it to PNG
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="bmp">the bmp file</param>
    /// <param name="filename">the file name</param>
    private static void SaveRTBAsPNG(RenderTargetBitmap bmp, string filename)
    {
      PngBitmapEncoder pngImage = new PngBitmapEncoder();

      pngImage.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bmp));
      using (var filestream = System.IO.File.Create(filename))
      {
        pngImage.Save(filestream);
      }
    }    
  }
```

**MY Output**

[image: Thisi si what I get after I save my .png]

**My Desired Output:**

[image: This is what I want to get. just the image and not the whole canvas]

As you can see, what I want to be able to do is save the actual image

Comment: Make the RenderTargetBitmap smaller...

Comment: I reckon if you make that a full answer you'd get the points :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are requesting a bitmap the size of the entire Window. Instead, you should make sure the canvas is the size you want and then use the canvas' height and width:

```
public static void SaveCanvas(Window window, Canvas canvas, int dpi, string filename)
{
    var rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap(
        (int)canvas.ActualWidth, //width 
        (int)canvas.ActualHeight, //height 
        dpi, //dpi x 
        dpi, //dpi y 
        PixelFormats.Pbgra32 // pixelformat 
        );
    rtb.Render(canvas);

    SaveRTBAsPNG(rtb, filename);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this makes a lot of sense. I had a feeling because I was snapping the whole canvas that the caveat was that I was gonna have to deal with that negative space. I'm glad it works now. Cheers!

Comment: it works to take a snapshot of the canvas BUT... it doesnt work when I just want to take a picture of an image within the canvas. I will update my question so you can see what I mean.

Comment: What is your image made up of? Is it a single image control? Is it several controls?

Comment: nvm it was my problem. I had to tailor the last part to save the actual image object and not the whole canvas. It works now and I marked your answer as the correct; as well it should be ;)